# Load new page using commandButton

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

On *http://mydomain.pl:8080/web/guest/addItem* I have a couple of portlets.
On one of them there is a portlet containing *commandButton* like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add item" action="#{itemsManagerBean.addItem}" />
```

where method looks like this:

```
    public String addItem() {
    // ...
    return "/anotherPortlet/view.xhtml";
}
```

It works, but it overload only this one portlet. I would like load **new page** *http://mydomain.pl:8080/web/guest/anotherPage* with another portlets...

What is best solution for this?

Comment: I don't do Portlets and I'm not sure what you mean with "overload" here, but don't you actually want to send a redirect after post? (or if the method does further completely nothing, just use a plain link?)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a full page reload, where the page has a completely different portlet on it than the page you are reloading? This would go way deeper into the portal's implementation than possible answering here. It might help to state your underlying business problem that you want to solve with this. There's definitely another solution for it, that's quick to do and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addItem() {
 ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
 try {
        externalContext.redirect("/web/guest/anotherPage");
     } catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: I got `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ChatAzure] threw exception [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config` ...

Comment: `jstl.jar` is missing. I have this jar in my server itself. Am using Liferay + Jboss AS. So I have this jar in `../deploy/jbossweb.sar/jstl.jar`. Check if you have this jar in your server..

Comment: Now I got `javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/web/guest/anotherPage.jsp" not found`Why '.jsp' is sticked there?

Comment: @DavidSilva It shouldn't happen like this. Edit your question and provide the full code (`h:commandLink` and the bean method) that you have now.

Comment: @DavidSilva Why don't you give a try with `h:commandLink` instead of `h:commandButton` ?